# A set $A$ is closed iff $\operatorname{fr}A\subseteq A$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

A set $A$ is closed iff $\operatorname{fr}A \subseteq A$.

MY attempt:
suppose $A$ is closed and let $x \in\operatorname{fr}A$. We must show $x \in A$. If $x \notin A$, then $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A$. Since $A$ is closed, then there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N \cap A =\varnothing$. This contradicts hypothesis that $x$ lies in the frontier of $A$, therefore, $x \in A$. So, $\operatorname{fr}A \subseteq A$. Is this direction correct?

conversely, if $\operatorname{fr}A \subseteq A$, we want to show $A$ is closed. In other words, we want to show that every $x \notin A$ is an exterior point, or that there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N \cap A =\varnothing$. If $N$ and $A$ overlap, then $x$ is a limit point of $A$. How can I reach a contradiction from this step?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: is $Fr(A)$ the closure of $A$?

Comment: @ThomasE. The frontier, i.e., boundary.

Comment: What definition of closed set do you use? Don't you have other equivalences to work with? Like $A=\bar A\iff A$ is closed or $\bar A=A\cup\partial A$?

Comment: A is closed is every $x \notin A$ is an exterior point.

Comment: @Citizen OK. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @Citizen. What definition of an exterior point do you use then?

Comment: $x$ is exterior point of $A$ is there exists a nghbd $N$ of $x$ such that $ x \in N \subseteq A^c$ (or that $N \cap A$ is empty)

Comment: The first part is correct.

For the second part to finish your argument, if $N\cap A \neq \emptyset$ for every neighbourhood of $x$, then $x \in Fr(A)$. But since $Fr(A) \subseteq A$, this contradicts $x \notin A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is that

> $A$ is closed if and only if $\partial A\subseteq A$.

**P** First, suppose $A$ is closed. Suppose that $x\notin A$. Then there exists a neighborhood $N_x$ of $x$ such that $N_x \cap A=\varnothing$. But this means $x\notin\partial A$, since $x\in\partial A$ if and only if each nbhd $N_x$ of $x$ intersects both $A$ and its complement. Thus $X\smallsetminus A \subseteq  X\smallsetminus \partial A $ which is equivalent to $\partial A\subseteq A$.

Now, suppose $\partial A\subseteq A$. Pick $x\notin A$, that is $x\in X\smallsetminus A$. Then $x\notin \partial A$. This means there exists a nbhd $N_x$ of $x$ such that $N_x\cap A=\varnothing$ or a nbhd $N_x'$ such that $N_x'\cap (X\setminus A)=\varnothing$. But $N_x'\cap (X\setminus A)$ is *not* empty since $x\in X\setminus A$, so it must be the case $N_x\cap A=\varnothing$, and $A$ is closed.

---

Note your first part of the proof isn't really a contradiction, you're effectively showing that $X\smallsetminus A \subseteq  X\smallsetminus \partial A $ which is the same as $\partial A\subseteq A$.